# How to select strategy to reduce overfitting?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am applying transfer-learning on a pre-trained network with keras. I have image patches with a binary class label and would like to use CNN to predict a class label in the range [0; 1] for unseen image patches.

- **network**: ResNet50 pre-trained with imageNet to which I add 3 layers
- **data**: 70305 training samples, 8000 validation samples, 66823 testing samples, all with a balanced number of both class labels
- **images**: 3 bands (RGB) and 224x224 pixels
- **set-up**: 32 batches, size of conv. layer: 16
- **result**: after a few epochs, I already have an accuracy of almost 1 and a loss close to 0, while on the validation data the accuracy remains at 0.5 and loss varies per epoch. In the end, the CNN predicts only one class for all unseen patches.
- **problem**: it seems like my network is overfitting.

[image: results screenshot]
[image]

The following strategies could reduce overfitting:

- increase batch size
- decrease size of fully-connected layer
- add drop-out layer
- add data augmentation
- apply regularization by modifying the loss function
- unfreeze more pre-trained layers
- use different network architecture

I have tried batch sizes up to 512 and changed the size of fully-connected layer without much success. Before just randomly testing the rest, **I would like to ask how to investigate what goes wrong why in order to find out which of the above strategies has most potential**.

Below my code:

```
def generate_data(imagePathTraining, imagesize, nBatches):
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory\
        (directory=imagePathTraining,                           # path to the target directory
         target_size=(imagesize,imagesize),                     # dimensions to which all images found will be resize
         color_mode='rgb',                                      # whether the images will be converted to have 1, 3, or 4 channels
         classes=None,                                          # optional list of class subdirectories
         class_mode='categorical',                              # type of label arrays that are returned
         batch_size=nBatches,                                   # size of the batches of data
         shuffle=True)                                          # whether to shuffle the data
    return generator

def create_model(imagesize, nBands, nClasses):
    print("%s: Creating the model..." % datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
    # Create pre-trained base model
    basemodel = ResNet50(include_top=False,                     # exclude final pooling and fully connected layer in the original model
                         weights='imagenet',                    # pre-training on ImageNet
                         input_tensor=None,                     # optional tensor to use as image input for the model
                         input_shape=(imagesize,                # shape tuple
                                      imagesize,
                                      nBands),
                         pooling=None,                          # output of the model will be the 4D tensor output of the last convolutional layer
                         classes=nClasses)                      # number of classes to classify images into
    print("%s: Base model created with %i layers and %i parameters." %
          (datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'),
           len(basemodel.layers),
           basemodel.count_params()))

    # Create new untrained layers
    x = basemodel.output
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)                             # global spatial average pooling layer
    x = Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)                         # fully-connected layer
    y = Dense(nClasses, activation='softmax')(x)                # logistic layer making sure that probabilities sum up to 1

    # Create model combining pre-trained base model and new untrained layers
    model = Model(inputs=basemodel.input,
                  outputs=y)
    print("%s: New model created with %i layers and %i parameters." %
          (datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'),
           len(model.layers),
           model.count_params()))

    # Freeze weights on pre-trained layers
    for layer in basemodel.layers:
        layer.trainable = False

    # Define learning optimizer
    optimizerSGD = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01,                      # learning rate.
                                  momentum=0.0,                 # parameter that accelerates SGD in the relevant direction and dampens oscillations
                                  decay=0.0,                    # learning rate decay over each update
                                  nesterov=False)               # whether to apply Nesterov momentum

    # Compile model
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizerSGD,                       # stochastic gradient descent optimizer
                  loss='categorical_crossentropy',              # objective function
                  metrics=['accuracy'],                         # metrics to be evaluated by the model during training and testing
                  loss_weights=None,                            # scalar coefficients to weight the loss contributions of different model outputs
                  sample_weight_mode=None,                      # sample-wise weights
                  weighted_metrics=None,                        # metrics to be evaluated and weighted by sample_weight or class_weight during training and testing
                  target_tensors=None)                          # tensor model's target, which will be fed with the target data during training
    print("%s: Model compiled." % datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'))
    return model

def train_model(model, nBatches, nEpochs, imagePathTraining, imagesize, nSamples, valX,valY, resultPath):
    history = model.fit_generator(generator=generate_data(imagePathTraining, imagesize, nBatches),
                                  steps_per_epoch=nSamples//nBatches,     # total number of steps (batches of samples)
                                  epochs=nEpochs,               # number of epochs to train the model
                                  verbose=2,                    # verbosity mode. 0 = silent, 1 = progress bar, 2 = one line per epoch
                                  callbacks=None,               # keras.callbacks.Callback instances to apply during training
                                  validation_data=(valX,valY),  # generator or tuple on which to evaluate the loss and any model metrics at the end of each epoch
                                  class_weight=None,            # optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function
                                  max_queue_size=10,            # maximum size for the generator queue
                                  workers=32,                   # maximum number of processes to spin up when using process-based threading
                                  use_multiprocessing=True,     # whether to use process-based threading
                                  shuffle=True,                 # whether to shuffle the order of the batches at the beginning of each epoch
                                  initial_epoch=0)              # epoch at which to start training
    print("%s: Model trained." % datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')) 
    return history
```

Comment: You are most definitely overfitting. Oscillations could mean your learning rate is too high since you are usng Stochastic Gradient Descent . I also see your decay_rate set to 0. You can try setting a lower learning_rate and using a different metric.

Comment: Do both classes have the same amount of labels?

Comment: @nihal: by reducing the learning rate, you mean reducing `lr=0.01` to a value closer to zero? What do you mean with a different metric? 'decay=0.0' was the default on the keras documention. I guess I need more insights into how the loss function parameters work.

Comment: @baschdl: yes, that's what I meant with '...all with a balanced number of both class labels'

Comment: Yes, @nihal meant reducing the ´lr´ parameter. Currently, you are using categorical crossentropy and could use another loss function but crossentropy should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestions above, I modified the following:

- I modified the learning optimizer (lowered learning rate to 0.001 and made adaptable to decay)
- I unified the data generators (same `ImageDataGenerator` for training and validation)
- I used a different pre-trained base CNN (VGG19 instead of ResNet50)
- I increased the number of nodes in the trainable fully connected layer (from 16 to 1024), which increased the final validation accuracy
- I increased the dropout rate (from 0.5 to 0.8), which minimized the gap between training and validation accuracy and thus limited over-fitting

```
    def generate_data(path, imagesize, nBatches):
        datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
        generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=path,     # path to the target directory
             target_size=(imagesize,imagesize),                     # dimensions to which all images found will be resize
             color_mode='rgb',                                      # whether the images will be converted to have 1, 3, or 4 channels
             classes=None,                                          # optional list of class subdirectories
             class_mode='categorical',                              # type of label arrays that are returned
             batch_size=nBatches,                                   # size of the batches of data
             shuffle=True,                                          # whether to shuffle the data
             seed=42)                                               # random seed for shuffling and transformations
        return generator
```

```
    def create_model(imagesize, nBands, nClasses):
        # Create pre-trained base model
        basemodel = VGG19(include_top=False,                        # exclude final pooling and fully connected layer in the original model
                             weights='imagenet',                    # pre-training on ImageNet
                             input_tensor=None,                     # optional tensor to use as image input for the model
                             input_shape=(imagesize,                # shape tuple
                                          imagesize,
                                          nBands),
                             pooling=None,                          # output of the model will be the 4D tensor output of the last convolutional layer
                             classes=nClasses)                      # number of classes to classify images into

        # Freeze weights on pre-trained layers
        for layer in basemodel.layers:
            layer.trainable = False   

        # Create new untrained layers
        x = basemodel.output
        x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)                             # global spatial average pooling layer
        x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)                       # fully-connected layer
        x = Dropout(rate=0.8)(x)                                    # dropout layer
        y = Dense(nClasses, activation='softmax')(x)                # logistic layer making sure that probabilities sum up to 1

        # Create model combining pre-trained base model and new untrained layers
        model = Model(inputs=basemodel.input,
                      outputs=y)

        # Define learning optimizer
        optimizerSGD = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.001,                     # learning rate.
                                      momentum=0.9,                 # parameter that accelerates SGD in the relevant direction and dampens oscillations
                                      decay=learningRate/nEpochs,   # learning rate decay over each update
                                      nesterov=True)                # whether to apply Nesterov momentum
        # Compile model
        model.compile(optimizer=optimizerSGD,                       # stochastic gradient descent optimizer
                      loss='categorical_crossentropy',              # objective function
                      metrics=['accuracy'],                         # metrics to be evaluated by the model during training and testing
                      loss_weights=None,                            # scalar coefficients to weight the loss contributions of different model outputs
                      sample_weight_mode=None,                      # sample-wise weights
                      weighted_metrics=None,                        # metrics to be evaluated and weighted by sample_weight or class_weight during training and testing
                      target_tensors=None)                          # tensor model's target, which will be fed with the target data during training
        return model
```

```
    def train_model(model, nBatches, nEpochs, trainGenerator, valGenerator, resultPath):
        history = model.fit_generator(generator=trainGenerator,
                                      steps_per_epoch=trainGenerator.samples // nBatches,   # total number of steps (batches of samples)
                                      epochs=nEpochs,               # number of epochs to train the model
                                      verbose=2,                    # verbosity mode. 0 = silent, 1 = progress bar, 2 = one line per epoch
                                      callbacks=None,               # keras.callbacks.Callback instances to apply during training
                                      validation_data=valGenerator, # generator or tuple on which to evaluate the loss and any model metrics at the end of each epoch
                                      validation_steps=
                                      valGenerator.samples // nBatches,                     # number of steps (batches of samples) to yield from validation_data generator before stopping at the end of every epoch
                                      class_weight=None,            # optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function
                                      max_queue_size=10,            # maximum size for the generator queue
                                      workers=1,                    # maximum number of processes to spin up when using process-based threading
                                      use_multiprocessing=False,    # whether to use process-based threading
                                      shuffle=True,                 # whether to shuffle the order of the batches at the beginning of each epoch
                                      initial_epoch=0)              # epoch at which to start training

        return history, model
```

[image: evaluation plot]

With these modifications, I achieved the following metrics for a batch size of 32 after training for 100 epochs:

- `train_acc`: 0.831
- `train_loss`: 0.436
- `val_acc`: 0.692
- `val_loss`: 0.568

I assume these settings optimal since:

- the curves for accuracy and loss behave similar for training and validation
- `train_acc` exceeds `val_acc` only after 30 epochs
- minimal over-fitting (small difference between `train_acc` and `val_acc`)
- `train_loss` and `val_loss` decrease continuously

However, I wonder:

- if I should train for more epochs to increase `val_acc` at the cost of more over-fitting
- why *f1-score*, *precision* and *recall* derived with `sklearn.metrics classification_report()` on `predict_generator()` predictions are all around 0.5, which indicates no learning for a 2-class classification.

Maybe, I should better open a new question on these issues.

Answer (score 0):

These results seem almost too bad to be a case of overfitting. Instead I suspect that there is a difference in the data used for training and for validation.

I note that for the training data you are using `ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)`, however for `valX` I do not see any such processing. I would recommend using a separate ImageDataGenerator with the same rescaling configuration also for the validation data. That way differences are as small as possible.

Comment: I now generate the validation data as the training data with `valGenerator = generate_data(imagePathValidation, imagesize, nBatches)` and updated the parameters in `fit_generator()` accordingly: `validation_data=valGenerator, validation_steps=valGenerator.samples//nBatches`. Also, I decreased the learning rate as suggested by @nihal. train_acc now increases slower, but val_acc remains at 0.5. The train_loss decreases linearly from 0.7 to 0.5 while val_loss oscillates between 1 and 3. Does this count as slow overfitting? Maybe I have to figure out how to make loss have a convex curve shape.

Comment: That sounds very odd. You should analyze a few batches and check that the labels and data looks reasonable

Comment: You should also try to replace the pretrained model which a tiny CNN model that you train from scratch. That way you can know if it is possible to learn at all with your setup

Comment: Also, try to reduce the number of samples per epoch to not be the entire dataset. It can make it easier to see the development. With so many images a lot of things Wil happen before first epoch is done

Comment: I now figured out why my `val_acc` remained at 0.5 (because I rescaled the images by 255 as I explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55569181/why-is-accuracy-from-fit-generator-different-to-that-from-evaluate-generator-in)). This in combination with modified learning optimizer settings, helped to reduce loss oscillations and to achieve a exponential curve shape for loss and accuracy. I will post an answer once I figured out optimal hyper parameters for my data.

Comment: yeah the `preprocessing_function` was probably the most critical one